# Securing Json Get Requests in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

All of the examples of the ng-grid (AngularUi grid component) use GET requests.

I am using CakePhp and have got an Action function in a controller which returns json.

Is there a way to secure GET requests to that Action function? Do I use the in-built security of CakePhp to restrict access to that controller?

At the moment, I can just load the route to it in a browser for the world to see. And that is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am looking for - SecurityComponent::$csrfCheck
Found at [the security component part of the API](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html).

I should have looked harder.
Thanks!